# This interaction failed - Buttons - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

"This interaction failed"
I'm trying to make buttons with discord.js, everything is good and the buttons work well, but even though it gives the error message "This interaction failed".
(This is the code)
Everyone talk about the "defer", and I don't understand.

I hope for some help :)

### **interactionCreate.js:**

````
let hastebin = require('hastebin');

module.exports = {
  name: 'interactionCreate',
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if (interaction.customId == "open-ticket") {
      if (client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guildId).channels.cache.find(c => c.topic == interaction.user.id)) {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: 'you have already a Ticket created!',
          ephemeral: true
        });
      };

      interaction.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${interaction.user.username}`, {
        parent: client.config.parentOpened,
        topic: interaction.user.id,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: interaction.user.id,
            allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
          },
          {
            id: client.config.roleSupport,
            allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
          },
          {
            id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          },
        ],
        type: 'text',
      }).then(async c => {
        interaction.reply({
          content: `Ticket has ben created! <#${c.id}>`,
          ephemeral: true
        });

        const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('ff9600')
          .setAuthor('Reason', ' ')
          .setDescription('choose a reason why you open a ticket')
          .setFooter('Ticket System', ' ')
          .setTimestamp();

        const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
            new client.discord.MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('category')
            .setPlaceholder('choose a reason why you open a ticket')
            .addOptions([{
                label: 'Apply',
                value: 'Apply',
                emoji: { name: '' }
              },
              {
                label: 'Support',
                value: 'Support',
                emoji: { name: '❓' }
              },
              {
                label: 'Complaint',
                value: 'Complaint',
                emoji: { name: '' }
              },
              {
                label: 'Hosting',
                value: 'Hosting',
                emoji: { name: '' }
              },
              {
                label: 'Partnership',
                value: 'Partnership',
                emoji: { name: '' }
              },
            ]),
          );

        msg = await c.send({
          content: `<@!${interaction.user.id}>`,
          embeds: [embed],
          components: [row]
        });

        const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
          componentType: 'SELECT_MENU',
          time: 20000
        });

        collector.on('collect', i => {
          if (i.user.id === interaction.user.id) {
            if (msg.deletable) {
              msg.delete().then(async () => {
                const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor('ff9600')
                  .setAuthor('Ticket', ' ')
                  .setDescription(`<@!${interaction.user.id}> has create a **Ticket** with the reason・ ${i.values[0]}`)
                  .setFooter('Ticket System', ' ')
                  .setTimestamp();

                const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
                  .addComponents(
                    new client.discord.MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('close-ticket')
                    .setLabel('close ticket')
                    .setEmoji('899745362137477181')
                    .setStyle('DANGER'),
                  );

                const opened = await c.send({
                  content: `<@&${client.config.roleSupport}>`,
                  embeds: [embed],
                  components: [row]
                });

                opened.pin().then(() => {
                  opened.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                });
              });
            };
            if (i.values[0] == 'Apply') {
              c.edit({
                parent: client.config.parentApply
              });
            };
            if (i.values[0] == 'Support') {
              c.edit({
                parent: client.config.parentSupport
              });
            };
            if (i.values[0] == 'Complaint') {
              c.edit({
                parent: client.config.parentComplaint
              });
            };
            if (i.values[0] == 'Hosting') {
              c.edit({
                parent: client.config.parentHosting
              });
            };
            if (i.values[0] == 'Partnership') {
              c.edit({
                parent: client.config.parentPartnership
              });
            };
          };
        });

        collector.on('end', collected => {
          if (collected.size < 1) {
            c.send(`There was no reason, the ticket will be closed.`).then(() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                if (c.deletable) {
                  c.delete();
                };
              }, 5000);
            });
          };
        });
      });
    };

    if (interaction.customId == "close-ticket") {
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guildId);
      const chan = guild.channels.cache.get(interaction.channelId);

      const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
          new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('confirm-close')
          .setLabel('Ticket close')
          .setStyle('DANGER'),
          new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('no')
          .setLabel('close cancel')
          .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
        );

      const verif = await interaction.reply({
        content: 'Are you sure you want to close the ticket?',
        components: [row]
      });

      const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
        componentType: 'BUTTON',
        time: 10000
      });

      collector.on('collect', i => {
        if (i.customId == 'confirm-close') {
          interaction.editReply({
            content: `The ticket has been closed by <@!${interaction.user.id}>`,
            components: []
          });

          chan.edit({
              name: `closed-${chan.name}`,
              permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                  id: client.users.cache.get(chan.topic),
                  deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                  id: client.config.roleSupport,
                  allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                  id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                  deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
              ],
            })
            .then(async () => {
              const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('ff9600')
                .setAuthor('Ticket', ' ')
                .setDescription('```Ticket saving```')
                .setFooter('Ticket System', ' ')
                .setTimestamp();

              const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                  new client.discord.MessageButton()
                  .setCustomId('delete-ticket')
                  .setLabel('Ticket delete')
                  .setEmoji('️')
                  .setStyle('DANGER'),
                );

              chan.send({
                embeds: [embed],
                components: [row]
              });
            });

          collector.stop();
        };
        if (i.customId == 'no') {
          interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Close ticket cancelled!',
            components: []
          });
          collector.stop();
        };
      });

      collector.on('end', (i) => {
        if (i.size < 1) {
          interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Ticket closure cancelled!',
            components: []
          });
        };
      });
    };

    if (interaction.customId == "delete-ticket") {
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guildId);
      const chan = guild.channels.cache.get(interaction.channelId);

      interaction.reply({
        content: 'ticket saving...'
      });

      chan.messages.fetch().then(async (messages) => {
        let a = messages.filter(m => m.author.bot !== true).map(m =>
          `${new Date(m.createdTimestamp).toLocaleString('de-DE')} - ${m.author.username}#${m.author.discriminator}: ${m.attachments.size > 0 ? m.attachments.first().proxyURL : m.content}`
        ).reverse().join('\n');
        if (a.length < 1) a = "It was not written in the ticket"
        hastebin.createPaste(a, {
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            server: 'https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/documents'
          }, {})
          .then(function (urlToPaste) {
            const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor('Logs Ticket', ' ')
              .setDescription(` Ticket-Logs \`${chan.id}\` created by <@!${chan.topic}> and deleted by <@!${interaction.user.id}>\n\nLogs: [**Click here to see the logs**](${urlToPaste})`)
              .setColor('2f3136')
              .setTimestamp();

            const embed2 = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor('Logs Ticket', ' ')
              .setDescription(` Logs of your ticket \`${chan.id}\`: [**Click here to see the logsn**](${urlToPaste})`)
              .setColor('2f3136')
              .setTimestamp();

            client.channels.cache.get(client.config.logsTicket).send({
              embeds: [embed]
            });
            client.users.cache.get(chan.topic).send({
              embeds: [embed2]
            }).catch(() => {console.log('I cant send it DM')});
            chan.send('Delete channel.');

            setTimeout(() => {
              chan.delete();
            }, 5000);
          });
      });
    };
  },
}; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `i.deferUpdate();` in your collector.

```
collector.on('collect', i => {
  i.deferUpdate();
  // code here
 })
```